# R read.delim error "no lines available in input"

Tags: r, read.table

I'm having trouble downloading a particular tab delimited dataset from the USGS.gov in base R using `read.delim` or `read.table`. I'm probably making an obvious mistake, but I can't seem to figure out what.

First, the following query functions fine in base R, and retrieves all water level data for the Markland Dam on the Ohio River. It also works for other dams.

```
Markland <- read.delim(("https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/ky/nwis/uv?cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=03277200&period=&begin_date=1950-09-30&end_date=2030-12-31"), 
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=28, header=TRUE)
```

However, my query for another table, the McAlpine Dam downstream, does not work. The data are structured almost identically. I've toyed with all of the read options provided in the read.table help, to no avail. I'm not sure what's different about this table, or what needs to change with this query.

```
McAlpine <- read.delim(("https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/ky/nwis/uv?cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=03294500&period=&begin_date=1950-09-30&end_date=2030-12-31"), 
            skipNul=TRUE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, sep = "\t", 
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=40, header=FALSE , fill=TRUE)
```

Here is the offending table: https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/ky/nwis/uv?cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=03294500&period=&begin_date=1950-09-30&end_date=2030-12-31

[image: Error Message]

[image: Table Screen shot]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe it's just particularly busy at the moment, but that query takes forever to return for me. If you can get it to work, a more robust approach would be to save it to a file locally with `download.file` or the like (given it's an API, [httr](http://httr.r-lib.org/) would be a good choice) before reading it in.

Comment: Hm, now that it returned, it's just the commented header lines with no actual data, which could also cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was actually able to make it work by breaking down the size of the query into single years. The table would load from USGS, but I guess R is timing out for some reason.

```
McAlpine2007 <- read.delim(("https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/ky/nwis/uv? 
cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=03294500&period=&begin_date=2007-01- 
01&end_date=2007-12-31"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=40, header=FALSE)

McAlpine2008 <- read.delim(("https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/ky/nwis/uv? 
cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=03294500&period=&begin_date=2008-01- 
01&end_date=2008-12-31"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=40, header=FALSE)

rbind(McAlpine2007,McAlpine2008)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given how long it takes to return the query, I think it is just timing out and assuming there are no data. You could use `httr` like alistaire suggested, or `RCurl` to just get the data with a specified `timeout`, then read it.

```
if(!require(RCurl)) {install.packages("RCurl"); library(RCurl)}

McAlp <- getURL("https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/ky/nwis/uv?cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=03294500&period=&begin_date=1950-09-30&end_date=2030-12-31", timeout = 300) # Try without a timeout, then add one if needed. It worked for me without a timeout argument.

McAlpine <- read.delim(textConnection(McAlp), sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip = 40, header = FALSE)

head(McAlpine)
    V1      V2               V3  V4    V5 V6
1 USGS 3294500 2007-10-01 03:30 EDT 10.27  A
2 USGS 3294500 2007-10-01 03:45 EDT 10.25  A
3 USGS 3294500 2007-10-01 04:00 EDT 10.22  A
4 USGS 3294500 2007-10-01 04:15 EDT 10.21  A
5 USGS 3294500 2007-10-01 04:30 EDT 10.22  A
6 USGS 3294500 2007-10-01 04:45 EDT 10.29  A
```